# Why can I static_cast void* to int* but not to int*&?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

An API uses `void*` to store untyped pointer offsets. It's a bit hacky, but okay whatever.

To express my offset arithmetic, I tried doing something like this

```
int main ()
{
    void * foo;

    foo = static_cast <int *> (nullptr) + 100;

    static_cast <int * &> (foo) += 100;
}
```

The last line fails to compile (gcc)

```
x.cpp:7:28: error: invalid static_cast from type ‘void*’ to type ‘int*&’
```

The fix is simple:

```
foo = static_cast <int *> (foo) + 100;
```

But why isn't the first one allowed?

Before you answer "because the standard says so", *why* does the standard say so? Is the first method somehow dangerous? Or is it just an oversight?

Comment: Theoretically, it is not guaranteed that `void*` and `int*` have the same size. As lvalue, they *might* be incompatible. Although it's impossible in practice.

Comment: @liliscent: In practice, `int*` requires fewer bits than `void*`, so while it may be rare, it's not impossible that they actually are different sizes (vs having a couple ununsed / padding bits in `int*`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not allowed for the same reason that `int i; static_cast<long &>(l) = 3L;` isn't allowed.

Sure, on a lot of implementations (where `int` and `long` have the same size, representation and alignment), it *could* work. But the rules for which casts are valid are mostly the same for all implementations, and clearly this could never work on platforms where `int` and `long` have different sizes, meaning it'd be impossible to allow accessing one as the other on those platforms.

Historically, there have been implementations on which `void *` and `int *` have different representations.

Later, after the standard stating that accessing `void *` as if it were an `int *` is invalid, implementations also started optimising on the assumption that valid programs do not do that:

```
void *f (void **ppv, int **ppi) {
  void *result = *ppv;
  *ppi = nullptr;
  return result;
}
```

The implementation is allowed to optimise this to

```
void *f (void **ppv, int **ppi) {
  *ppi = nullptr;
  return *ppv;
}
```

and such optimisations, when they reduce code size or increase efficiency, are commonplace nowadays. If `f` were allowed to be called as `void *pv = &pv; f (pv, &static_cast<int*&>(pv));`, this optimisation would be invalid. Because such optimisations have proved useful, the rules are unlikely to change.

Comment: The final example is really convincing, previously I think those difference is only theoretical. Tested for clang, this optimization is done even for `-O1`.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. But why isn't my `x=static_cast<int*>(x)+n` fix also forbidden?

Comment: @spraff That's like `int i = 3; i = static_cast<long>(i) + 1L;`. There's no re-interpretation of bits going on there, only conversion of values. Even if `void *` and `int *` were to have different representations, then the `static_cast<int*>(x)` will change the representation, `n` will be added, and the implicit conversion back to `void *` will change the representation back.